# "I was doing something" with present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Yesterday I posted this message on an online forum:

> I've fixed that bug while I was reviewing the code.

But I'm not sure it's correct. I understand that *I was reviewing the code* is a finished event and the **act** of fixing the bug is finished as well, but its **consequences** affect the present (something is now working because a bug no longer exists).

Is my reasoning correct or should I always use simple past when *I was doing something* is in the same sentence (or context)?

Comment: The addition of the *while* clause means you need simple past:  *I fixed that bug while I was reviewing the code*  By itself, "I've fixed that bug" is fine, however.

Comment: @Jim So in this case it doesn't matter if the past event still affects the present, right?

Comment: I'm no grammarian - but I'd consider it in 2 'envelopes'... 'while I was there' - past tense envelope, containing 'I fixed it' - present tense envelope; living forever as a captured moment inside the past tense envelope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use the past simple and the past continuous tenses in the sentence. The past continuous describes a longer, ‘background’ action and the past simple describes a short action. The correct sentence is:

> I fixed the bug while I was reviewing the code.